# How gitlab show fork branch ahead or behind upstream branch like github?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

In github web ui, we can see the sync status message of our fork project branch is ahead or behind of upstream project branch, just like :

`This branch is 1 commit ahead of [projectName]:[branchName].`

But in gitlab, I can't find it!

My Question is :
**Is there some way to show this kind of message in gitlab web ui?**

Comment: I suggest you search for and comment, or else create, a feature-request on the Gitlab CE issue tracker, if you can't find a feature request on Gitlab CE issue tracker that addresses this.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this is not currently possible.

I am actually working towards something similar, but I will probably end up writing a script to fetch and compare the logs of various repos, so I can do this from my own developer machine shell.

Comment: So regretful ! Thanks for you reply!